# Why (int* char d) is not printing it's memory address in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Why int* char **d** is not printing address of y whereas, **c** is printing memory address of **a**?
#include 
using namespace std;

```
int main () {

int a = 2;   // Initialization of a
int b = 3;   // Initialization of b

char y = 'A';
char z = 'B';

int* c =  &a ;  // c pointing address of a
char* d = &y ;  // d pointing address of y

*c = 32 ;
*d = 'D' ;

cout<< *c <<" "<< *d << endl;  // d is  printing 'D'

cout<< c <<" "<< d << endl;  // d should print memory address instead of 'D'

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should add though, that in you case the program has undefined behavior, because `d` doesn't actually point to a null terminated string, just a single non-null character. For details on why it is treated as a null terminated string, see linked duplicate.